# Is it possible to git ls-remote pushUrl with a single command?

Tags: git

I'd like to list the refs available in the repository I am pushing to which is different from the one I am pulling from. `git remote --push` supports this. But `git ls-remote` doesn't seem to have an option. I can do:

```
git ls-remote $(git remote get-url --push origin)
```

Is there a way to do this with a single command? Some way to specify the pushUrl target of a named remote?

Comment: have you ever considered using git aliases ? One says they are great https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases